# Writing to existing JSON array with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

**Disclaimer:** I am very unfamiliar with PHP. The answers I have seen floating around Stack don't seem applicable to my situation. This could be due to my unfamiliarity.

I need to write to an existing array in a JSON file:

```
[
    [
        // data should be written to this array
    ],
    []
]
```

My PHP looks like so:

```
<?php
    $ip = $_POST["ip"];
    $likes = "../data/likes.json";
    $fp = fopen($likes, "a");
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($ip) . ", ");
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

When the PHP runs it writes to the end of the file like so (as you'd expect):

```
[
    [

    ],
    []

]"data",
```

How do I resolve my PHP to do so?

Comment: Expected output ?

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file:

```
$filename = '../data/likes.json'
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
```

Then read the existing data structure into a variable:

```
$data = json_decode(fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
```

Add the data to the correct array entry:

```
$data[0][] = $ip;
```

Close and reopen the file with write privileges, so that we overwrite its contents:

```
fclose($fp);
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
```

And write the new JSON:

```
fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: This isn't serving me an error, but nor is it writing anything to the file.

Comment: Sorry, I left my dev file name in there for the second fopen. Fixing...

Comment: Now this script serves me up a 500 erorr

Comment: Ah. Nope. Now there was an error in my rewrite. Thanks for this. This has done it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = $_POST["ip"];
$likes = json_decode(file_get_contents("../data/likes.json"), true);
$likes[] = $ip;
file_put_contents("../data/likes.json", json_encode($likes));
```

You can not fimply add record to file and get valid json jbject.
So idea of that code:
we read all from file, append array with new data, and rewrite file with new data